# react-router-dom isActive setState in Infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are configuring the project using react-router-dom. I created a code to make the icons different depending on the rendered page, but an infinite loop occurs in the setState part. Help me.

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1X3f.png)

```js
class Bottom extends React.Component {
  state = {
    iconName : 'initialIconName'
  }

  setIconName = (name) => {
    this.setState(() =>({
        iconName: name
    }))
}

    render() {
      const oddEvent = (match, location) => {
        if (!match) return false
        console.log(location.pathname.substr(1).split('/')[0])
        this.setState(() => ({
          iconName: location.pathname.substr(1).split('/')[0]
        }))
        }

      return (
          <fragment>
            <div className="bottom noright">
              <div className="bottomcontents">
                <div className="bottomicon">
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" src={home} exact to="/" isActive={oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./home${this.state.iconName == 'home' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" exact to="/search" isActive={oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./search${this.state.iconName == 'search' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" to="/add" isActive={oddEvent} >
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./add${this.state.iconName == 'add' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" to="/account" isActive={oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./account${this.state.iconName == 'account' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="bottomiconinside bottomiconinsideside" exact to="/setting" isActive={oddEvent}>
                    <img className="iconcenter" src={require(`./setting${this.state.iconName == 'setting' ? 'sel' : ''}.svg`)}/>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                {/* <div className="search"></div>
                <div className="plus"></div>
                <div className="mypage"></div>
                <div className="setting"></div> */}
              </div>
            </div>
              </fragment>
        );
    }

  }

export default Bottom;
```

Comment: never ever call a `setState()` inside of the `render()` method due to it will re-render each time the state was set again

Answer (score 0):

React has so called `lifecycles` in it's components. After setting the state, the component will re-render. So you may not use the `setState()` method inside `render()`, `componentDidUpdate()` and so on. Otherwise the component will set a new state, render again, set a new state, render again......

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important thing to remember when you use reactJS. setState() will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. DO NOT USE setState IN,

1. shouldComponentUpdate
2. componentWillUpdate
3. render
4. componentWillUnmount

CALLING setState in above first 3 components will lead you to infinite loop while 4th one will not even leave a component to render